# Properties of probability matrix for random variables

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I have to show that given a rank one matrix $A$ for two discrete random variables $M_1$ and $M_2$ it is possible to factor $A$ as a product of two vectors where the $L1$ norm of those vectors is one. I have been able to complete the first part, but I must be missing some key feature of a probability matrix since I cannot come up with any argument why the $L1$ norm of the factored vectors has to be equal to one. We trivially know that all entries in $A$ are non-negative and thus are non-negative in the factored vectors. I do not see how that helps.

Comment: What is the definition of a "matrix for two discrete random variables"?

Comment: @Adam All entries are non-negative and all cells sum to one?

Comment: Do you mean all rows sum to 1?  Is it like $A_{ij} = \mathbb{P}(M_2 = j | M_1 = i)$?

Comment: @Adam  My assignment defines $A_{ij} = \mathbb{P}(M_1 = i, M_2 = j)$. I was under the impression that such matrix is a common one (at least my lecturer gives such an impression), my bad for not providing sufficient information.

Comment: Are $M_1$ and $M_2$ assumed to be independent?

Comment: @Adam No, but that is the last thing to show in the problem. Namely that since $A$ is rank one and can be factored it follows that the sum of entries in the factored vectors is one, which in turn implies that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the entries $A_{ij} = \mathbb{P}(M_1 = i, M_2 = j) = \mathbb{P}(M_1 = i) \mathbb{P}(M_2 = j | M_1 = i)$.  Since we are given that $A$ has rank $1$, we know (for example) that the first and second rows of $A$ are scalar multiplies of each other, i.e. that $A_{1j}/A_{2j}$ is constant in $j$.  By the definition of $A$ this says that
$$
\frac{\mathbb{P}(M_1 = 1) \mathbb{P}(M_2 = j | M_1 = 1)}{\mathbb{P}(M_1 = 2) \mathbb{P}(M_2 = j | M_1 = 2)}
$$
is constant in $j$, so also
$$
\frac{ \mathbb{P}(M_2 = j | M_1 = 1)}{ \mathbb{P}(M_2 = j | M_1 = 2)}
$$
is constant in $j$.  This shows that the two vectors $\text{Law}(M_2 | M_1 = 1)$ and $\text{Law}(M_2 | M_1 = 2)$ are scalar multiples of each other.  But since they are also both probability laws, they must also both sum to $1$ and therefore they must be equal.  Since the matrix $A$ has rank $1$, this same argument applies to any two rows of $A$ and therefore we can conclude that the conditional distribution $\text{Law}(M_2 | M_1 = i)$ is the same distribution for any $i$.  This in fact implies that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are independent.

Now that we have established that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are independent, we know that the matrix $A$ actually takes the form $A_{ij} = \mathbb{P}(M_1 = i) \mathbb{P}(M_2 = j)$ so we get the factorization
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{P}(M_1 = 1) \\ \vdots \\ \mathbb{P}(M_1 = n) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{P}(M_2 = 1) & \cdots & \mathbb{P}(M_2 = m)\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Written this way it's clear that the entries of both vectors sum to $1$ because they are just the distributions of $M_1$ and $M_2$.